# simple regex to matching multiple word with spaces/multiple space or no spaces

Tags: javascript, java, regex, string

I am trying to match all words with single or multiple spaces. my expression

(\w+\s*)*  is not working

edit 1:
Let say i have a sentence in this form

```
[[do "hi i am bob"]]
[[do "hi   i am Bob"]]

now I have to replace this with 
cool("hi i am bob") or 
cool("hi    i am Bob")
```

I do not care about replacing multiple spaces with single .

I can achieve this for a single word like

`\[\[do\"(\w+)\"\]\] and replacing regex cool\(\"$1\")` but this does not look like an effective solution and does not match multiple words ....
I apologies for incomplete question

any help will be aprecciated

Comment: What are you really try to accomplish?  Are you trying to isolate each word?  Find a sequence of characters not including punctuation?  What exactly is the actual goal here?

Comment: whatchu trying to get out of that there regex?>

Comment: @jfriend00 & thatidiotguy my apologies for incomplete question .Please check I have updated the question

Comment: What a rapid edit - now some "old" answers look like dumb ones.

Comment: -1 agree with @Ωmega, with the update this thread is pretty much useless for future generations...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find this Regular Expression:

```
/\[\[do\s+("[\w\s]+")\s*\]\]/
```

And do the following replacement:

```
'cool($1)'
```

The only special thing that's being done here is using character classes to our advantage with

```
[\w\s]+
```

Matches one or more word or space characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _, and whitespace).  That';; eat up your internal stuff no problem.

```
'[[do "hi   i am Bob"]]'.replace(/\[\[do\s+("[\w\s]+")\s*\]\]/, 'cool($1)')
```

Spits out

```
cool("hi   i am Bob")
```

Though - if you want to add punctuation (which you probably will), you should do it like this:

```
/\[\[do\s+("[^"]+")\s*\]\]/
```

Which will match any character that's not a double quote, preserving your substring.  There are more complicated ones to allow you to deal with escaped quotation marks, but I think that's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: @Christophe Yeah, I didn't see the second part of your answer.  Though technically, your answer matches a lot of things OP probably doesn't want.  Newlines, and extra double quotes.  Try this: `'[[do "hi i am bob"]]\n[[do "hi   i am Bob"]]'.replace(/\[\[do "([\s\S]+)"\]\]/, 'cool("$1")')` - it gives some unexpected results.

Comment: oh, now that I look at it, mine matches newlines, too.  Though it won't match quotation marks, which is likely okay.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan until you meet somebody called John-Paul or O'Brian ;-)

Answer (score 2):

To match "all words with single or multiple spaces", you cannot use `\s*`, as it will match even no spaces.

On the other hand, it looks like you want to match even "hi", which is one word with no spaces.

You probably want to match one or more words separated by spaces. If so, use regex pattern

```
(\w+(?:$|\s+))+
```

or

```
\w+(\s+\w+)*
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe this is what you're trying to get:

```
"Hi I am bob".match(/\b\w+\b/g);  // ["Hi", "I", "am", "bob"]
```

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña JavaScript doesn't work well with Unicode characters in regular expressions, hence `\b` sequence won't work. Instead it's more easy to split your string by one or many space characters with the following code: `'Hi I am acuña'.split(/\s+/);`.

Answer (score 0):

What your regex is doing is:

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,}[ \r\v\n\t\f]{0,}){0,}/
```

That is, find the first match of one or more of A through Z bother lower and upper along with digits and underscore, then followed by zero or more space characters which are:

- A space character
- A carriage return character
- A vertical tab character
- A new line character
- A tab character
- A form feed character

Then followed by zero or more of A through Z bother lower and upper along with digits and underscore.

`\s` matches more than just simple spaces, you can put in a literal space, and it will work.

I believe you want:

```
/(\w+ +\w+)/g
```

Which **all** matches of one or more of A through Z bother lower and upper along with digits and underscore, followed by **one** or more spaces, then followed by one or more of A through Z bother lower and upper along with digits and underscore.

This will match all *word-characters* separated by spaces.

If you just want to find all clusters of word characters, without punctuation or spaces, then, you would use:

```
/(\w+)/g
```

Which will find all *word-characters* that are grouped together.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Match all groups of characters that are not white spaces

```
var str = "Hi I   am   Bob";

var matches = str.match(/[^ ]+/g); // => ["Hi", "I", "am", "Bob"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var regex=/\w+\s+/g;
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GngWn/

[Update] I was just answering the question, but based on the comments this is more likely what you're looking for:

```
var regex=/\b\w+\b/g;
```

\b are word boundaries.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GngWn/2/

[Update2] Your edit makes it a completely different question:

```
string.replace(/\[\[do "([\s\S]+)"\]\]/,'cool("$1")');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GngWn/3/

Comment: Where is the final "Bob"? :) Or I misunderstood the question?

Comment: That would includes trailing spaces (if exist), which are probably unwanted (http://jsfiddle.net/GngWn/1/)

Comment: @VisioN I am just answering the question: "match all words with single or multiple spaces" the last Bob is not one of them.

Comment: @Ωmega same comment, I am just answering the question and you're probably right.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex pattern `\w+(\s+\w+)*` as follows:

```
m = s.match(/\w+(\s+\w+)*/g);
```

Comment: God, no.  This pattern is just waiting for catastrophic backtracking.  Use `/\w([\w\s]*\w)?/`

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan - You are joking right? This pattern is a good one.

Comment: @Ωmega - The pattern is technically correct, but dangerous due to catastrophic backtracking.  Nested Quantifiers are a dangerous thing, especially in a language as inefficient as Javascript.  http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html  This article gives a good intro to the idea.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan - Hey, kid. You don't have to teach me, I do know what catastrophic backtracking is for decades, but in this case it is impossible.